# Neo4j join and intersect two optional queries

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have streams with  relations with categories and users, but those relations are optional relations. So streams should not always be related to a category or user, it may just related to a category or multiple categories or users. My question is I want to join two optional queries which handle all those cases. Example below, behaves like this, it works if both category and user relations exists for node, but does not work if node has only a user relation in example.Any ideas?

```
MATCH (stream:Stream {id: "xyz123"})
MATCH (stream)-[:CONTAINS]->(categories)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo), (stream)<-[:PARTICIPANT_OF]-(users)<-[:OWNER]-(photo)
WHERE photo.is_private=false
return collect(photo.id) as photo_ids
```

What i need is intersection of two matchings if both user and category relations exists. if only category or user relations exists bring only the result of that relation

Comment: Your first `MATCH` clause is malformed. Please fix.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (stream:Stream { id: "xyz123" })
OPTIONAL MATCH (stream)-[:CONTAINS]->(categories)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo)
WHERE photo.is_private=false
WITH stream, COLLECT(photo) AS p1
OPTIONAL MATCH (stream)<-[:PARTICIPANT_OF]-(users)<-[:OWNER]-(photo)
WHERE photo.is_private=false
WITH stream, p1 + COLLECT(photo) AS pCombined
UNWIND pCombined AS photo
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT photo.id) AS photo_ids
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=z3q9y6) that shows this query working.

Comment: unfortunately return empty in all cases now

Comment: I have added to my answer a link to a console that shows this query working. Please take a look and indicate any significant differences from your situation.

Comment: thanks, this works but what i need is intersection of queries, now it works but also brings photos not belong to stream categories if there is a category relation, if there is user relation it brings all the photos of the user do not matter about the category. What i need is intersection of the category and user if both exists